# Creating single chart from three categoric values using python

Tags: python, charts, categorical-data

I am fairly new to python and its terminology and can be clumsy at describing the problem.Sorry for that.

What I got is three cities that produced three fruits for two years, and I need to draw the single-static chart that summarizes the data best.

The fact that dataframe have 3 categoric values (city, fruits and year) and one measure makes me confused.

At first I try to use stack bar chart, however If I use fruits in the bars and cities in X axis, I could not find where to use year value.
I tried to use pivot method to convert year value into measure, but I could not advance with two measures this time.
I mainly used Matplotlib.
Any help appreciated,

```
data= {
    'city':['amsterdam','amsterdam','amsterdam','amsterdam','amsterdam','amsterdam','paris','paris','paris','paris','paris','paris','berlin','berlin','berlin','berlin','berlin','berlin'],
    'fruits':['apples','oranges','bananas','apples','oranges','bananas','apples','oranges','bananas','apples','oranges','bananas','apples','oranges','bananas','apples','oranges','bananas'],
    'year':[2000,2000,2000,2001,2001,2001,2000,2000,2000,2001,2001,2001,2000,2000,2000,2001,2001,2001],
    'amount':[384,289,347,242,390,274,175,334,245,116,252,366,255,400,300,240,600,180] 
  }
```

df=pd.DataFrame(data)

df.head()

|  | city | fruits | year | amount |
| --- | --- | --- | --- | --- |
| 0 | paris | apples | 2000 | 384 |
| 1 | paris | oranges | 2000 | 289 |
| 2 | paris | bananas | 2000 | 347 |
| 3 | paris | apples | 2001 | 242 |
| 4 | paris | oranges | 2001 | 390 |